# Sony Vaio randomly shuts down

Tags: shutdown, vaio

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a Sony Vaio Laptop. I'm trying to learn the Linux operating system.

I have a alight issue in that the computer randomly shuts down.  It seems to go through the normal shutdown routine without user request.  Something (and I don't know what) seems to be requesting the shutdown.

How can I work out what is requesting this shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

Is this fresh installed system? Check the power settings that you select any shutdown option for power issue

[image]

If it does not solve the problem then we need your system log. Provide the system log if it can not solve the problem.